# How to return resultStatus from a T result method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am looking for some help to understand how to return on an Exception from a `T result`. I like to return this `ResultStatus` but I get an error that I can't convert ResultStatus to `T result`. Is there any way to do this? If I do this `T result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>("");` that object is null.

```
    public static T Post<T>(string httpMethod, string url, object model)
    {
        try
        {
            var fullUrl = cmsApiUrl + url;

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);

            Stream dataStream = null;
            WebRequest Webrequest;
            Webrequest = WebRequest.Create(fullUrl);


            Webrequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            Webrequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;

            Webrequest.PreAuthenticate = true;
            Webrequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + cmsApiKey);

            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json);

            Webrequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            dataStream = Webrequest.GetRequestStream();

            using (dataStream = Webrequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }

            WebResponse response = Webrequest.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            output.Append(reader.ReadToEnd());
            response.Close();

            T result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(output.ToString());
            return result;
        }

        catch (WebException e)
        {
                ResultStatus resulterrorStatus = new ResultStatus();
            

                return resulterrorStatus;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            T result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>("");
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e);
            return result;
        }
    }
```